# How can I iterate over two or more template indexes with Haystack, Whoosh and Django

Tags: indexing, django-haystack, whoosh

I was reading the docs and some questions around here and couldn't understand how can I return a query that has fields indexed in two different classes. Let me put the code below:

Here I have the classes:

```
class T031003Index(RealTimeSearchIndex):
text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
C003INST = IntegerField(model_attr='C003INST')
C003CHCD = CharField(model_attr='C003CHCD')
C003MTR = CharField(model_attr='C003MTR')
C003RZSC = CharField(model_attr='C003RZSC')

def index_queryset(self):
    return T031003.objects.all()

def prepare(self, obj):
    self.prepared_data = super(T031003Index, self).prepare(obj)
    self.prepared_data['text'] = obj.C003CHCD
    return self.prepared_data

site.register(T031003, T031003Index)
```

And the second one:

```
class T031002Index(RealTimeSearchIndex):
text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
C002USER = CharField(model_attr='C002USER')

def index_queryset(self):
    return T031002.objects.all()

def prepare(self, obj):
    self.prepared_data = super(T031002Index, self).prepare(obj)
    self.prepared_data['text'] = obj.C002USER
    return self.prepared_data
site.register(T031002, T031002Index)
```

And I have two template indexes for each of them:

T031003_text:

```
{{ object.C003INST }}
{{ object.C003CHCD }}
{{ object.C003MTR }}
{{ object.C003RZSC }}
```

T031002_text:

```
{{ object.C002USER }}
{{ object.C002INST }}
```

My template code:

```
{% if page.object_list %}    
{% for object in page.object_list %}
    <br>
    <li><font class="font">
      {{ object.C003RZSC }}, {{ object.C003INST }}, {{ object.C003CHCD }}, {{ object.C003MTR }}, {{ object.C002USER }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

My view:

```
def search(req):
return SearchView(template='search.html')(req)
```

If I type in the search box a value from a field, let's say, that belongs to class T031002Index (like user = "vane"), it gives me the result:

"None, None, None, None, vane"

And, if I type a value from a field in class T031003Index, it gives me the result:

"pencil, 1, school material, general, None"

I have between these two classes in models.py a Foreign Key field, which is C002INST.

Could you guys give me an explanation? It seems easy, but I can't figure it out by myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was reading now the Haystack's index page and something caught my attention: "Meanwhile, work on 2.0.0-alpha has hit master, including the long-awaited addition of **multiple index support**. Similar to Django's multidb support, this will allow you to talk to multiple search engines at the same time. Things like master-slave setups, a separate engine for autocomplete or split public-facing/admin-only search are now trivial..." Is that it? I can't do what I plan in my question if Im not using 2.0 Haystack version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a little help from close friends and a lot of research, I could find the solution.

1)I made an upgrade from Haystack 1.2.6 to Haystack 2.0.0

2)In my view, I changed the code to use AutoQuery and SearchQuerySet. It let's you use more that one word to search content and let's you filter results.

Here's the view:

```
def search(request):
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=AutoQuery(request.GET['q']))
return  render_to_response('search.html', {'sqs': sqs,})
```

4) Now, in "search_indexes.py", I changed the code to follow 2.0.0 version of Haystack and took off the "model_attr" from the foreign key (T031002Index, C002INST field).

Here's the code:

```
class T031003Index(RealTimeSearchIndex,Indexable):
   text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   C003INST = IntegerField(model_attr='C003INST')
   C003CHCD = CharField(model_attr='C003CHCD')
   C003MTR = CharField(model_attr='C003MTR')
   C003RZSC = CharField(model_attr='C003RZSC')

def index_queryset(self):
    return T031003.objects.all()

def get_model(self):
    return T031003


class T031002Index(RealTimeSearchIndex,Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    C002INST = CharField()
    C002USER = CharField(model_attr='C002USER')

def index_queryset(self):
    return T031002.objects.all()

def get_model(self):
    return T031002
```

But even with all these changes, Haystack would iterate over the two indexes and would return null results. This is wrong and also would lead the user to confusion. So, I changed the template to show me the fields only when they have results which are not null:

```
{% if page.object_list %}    
{% for result in page.object_list %}
    {% if result.object.C003MTR%}
    <li><b>Matrícula:</b> {{ result.object.C003MTR }}</li>
    <li><b>CPF/CNPJ:</b> {{ result.object.C003CHCD }}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if result.object.C002INST %}
    <li><b>ID Instituição:</b> {{ result.object.C002INST }}</li>
    <li><b>Usuário:</b> {{ result.object.C002USER }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

The "if" will do the trick to test if the field has null results.

Hope it helps other developers using Haystack with Django.